# no viable alternative at input 'is false'

Tags: hiveql, presto, amazon-athena

trying to query database in aws athena but got this error:

```
WHERE
    "fo0"."date" > date'2014-08-03'
        AND "re0"."rating" IS NOT NULL
        AND "fi0"."is_side" is FALSE
GROUP BY "Name"
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT "re0"."id") > 10
ORDER BY "% More Loves than Dislikes" DESC
;
```

I am pretty new to athena. Any resolve is helpful.

Comment: Where is the error?  It looks like you've just included the query

Comment: error is :line 34:32: no viable alternative at input 'is false' (service: amazonathena; status code: 400; error code: invalidrequestexception; request id: 9fbac92c-5aad-11e7-8a5d-25b8cdc83b46)

Comment: Are you trying to call the date function here: `"fo0"."date" > date'2014-08-03'` - should it instead be: `"fo0"."date" > date('2014-08-03')` ?  Also, the error message is pointing you in the right direction to look at the `is FALSE` evaluation.  Shouldn't that be `= FALSE` ?

Comment: date function was giving a error but i gave a datatype in front of the the date and it resolved the error. Now i am getting error in "fi0"."is_side" is FALSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you may need to change this line:

```
AND "fi0"."is_side" is FALSE
```

to:

```
AND "fi0"."is_side" = FALSE
```

Since it sounds like your `is_side` datatype is a `tinyint`, try the following:

```
ND "fi0"."is_side" = 0
```

Comment: tried it already. got the following errorSYNTAX_ERROR: line 34:29: '=' cannot be applied to tinyint, boolean

Comment: Ahh, if you're data type is a tinyint, can you compare it against 0?

Comment: Welcome Prashant Rai - please accept the answer if you don't mind and good luck with your project